# Find the function from the given conditions :-

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

Conditions: $$
f(x+h)=e^{x} f(h)+e^{h} f(x)
$$ and $$
\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=0
$$
I have tried to approach this problem by framing the function in the form  of f(X+h) but I am stuck here$$
f(x+1)=e^{x+h}\left(\frac{f(x)}{e^{x}}+\frac{f(h)}{e^{h}}\right)
$$ please help

Comment: Taking the limit for $h$ and you have $f(x+1)=f(x)$.

Comment: Hint: $$
\frac{{f(x + h) - f(x)}}{h} = e^x \frac{{f(h)}}{h} + \frac{{e^h  - 1}}{h}f(x).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f$ is differentiable, since
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} &= \frac{e^x f(h) + e^h f(x) - f(x)}{h} \\
&= e^x \frac{f(h)}{h} + f(x) \frac{e^h - 1}{h} \\
&\to e^x \cdot 0 + f(x) \cdot 1 = f(x),
\end{align*}
as $h \to 0$. We additionally get $f' = f$, hence $f(x) = ke^x$ for some $k$.

But, given the condition $\frac{f(x)}{x} \to 0$, we get
$$ke^x = f(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x} \cdot x \to 0 \cdot 0 = 0$$
and $ke^x \to k$ as $x \to 0$. Thus, $k = 0$, and $f \equiv 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible way forward:  there is a big hint given in the second condition which states a limiting value for $f(x)/x$ as $x \to 0$.  That prompts one to try to adapt $f(x+h) - f(x)$ to the definition of the derivative of $f$ at $x$.  If you do that, you may deduce a simple first order differential equation for $f$ and thence obtain the expression for $f$ itself.